# Translucent Status Bar is not translucent

Tags: android, material-design

I've tried to implement translucent action bar, like described [here](https://material.io/components/app-bars-top/android#regular-top-app-bar):

effect should be like this:

[image]

I've made following changes to my layout:

```
> <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".fragments.HotelFragment">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            .....
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/d" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                     ....
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
               />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

In themes:

```
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>>
```

Effect is like:

[image]

My minimum API is 21.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in activity.
window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)

Comment: It works, but navigation bar has no additional space in form of this status bar. Status bar is kinda included in Toolbar.